# Amazon Cognito: How to pass credentials to server-side application

Tags: amazon-iam, amazon-cognito, aws-sts

I have a client side application (developed in Java, not Android) that authenticate a user with an Amazon Cognito User Pool. To make things clear: that application display a username/password entry dialog, then authenticate with the Cognito user pool service using the SRP method; potential challenges are handled in that dialog (device id, password must be changed, two factors, etc). In the end, I have a series of tokens that allow the program to use AWS services with the user's credentials.

Now, I need the client application to communicate with a custom server side application. The client will have to prove its identity to the server application, which will then communicate with more AWS services. Here, I have two distinct use case:

1) The server only needs to *know* who the client-authenticated user is (in a safe manners, but without impersonating the user).

2) The client needs to *delegate* some or all of privileges of the user to the server; the server will then perform some actions on AWS services under that users behalf.

The server side application will most likely be developed in Java, running on an EC2 machine. I'm only interested in user authentification through the Cognito user pool source (that is, I have no interest in Facebook/Google/OpenID-based authentication flows).

It seems rather easy to achieve both objectives in very unsafe manners: just have the client application send to the server all the tokens it has been granted. But this is obviously not the way to go.

Yet, I'm having a hard time figuring out from Cognito User Pool/Cognito Identity Pool/IAM/STS documentation how this can be correctly achieved. I would expect for example the possibility for the client application to be able to generate some kind of "delegation token", which can be passed to the server; the server should then be able to validate that token and extract identity information from it (satisfying #1), or to impersonate the identity corresponding to the token in order to perform calls to AWS services (satisfying #2). Or maybe I'm thinking this incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are pointing at is OAuth 2.0 code grant flow which is not currently supported by Amazon Cognito.

The current available safe way to do this is to pass the id token from the client to the server and then validate that token and extract identity information from it. This proves the identity of the caller as you can validate the signature of the id token.

Comment: I had some faint memory that OAuth 2 had a specific flow for this purpose, though I couldn't remember the name of it. Thanks for point it out.

Now, ain't it risky to share the id token from the client to the server? Sure I can pass it over SSL, but still... What would be the potential risk of it being disclosed? There is the evident one that someone could impersonate the user in regard of my specific server, but would it be possible to do more than this?